NTP configuration : authentication, authorization and syslog
I hope you are fine,
I build a three NTP servers each with (chrony , openntpd and NTPsec )
and one ubuntu server that Monitoring NTP Traffic :
1- Zeek and Suricata generate logs
2- Logs are sent to syslog.
3- Logstash reads logs from syslog and processes them.
4- Logstash sends processed logs to Elasticsearch.
5- Kibana accesses Elasticsearch for visualization and alerting.
my question is how to :
authenticates timestamps and acess control ?
